# Define certain enter and exit transitions for specific views in activity

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I am adding activity transitions using [this](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) documentation.  I understand that I can define enter and exit transitions for the entire activity, such as [explode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/master/screenshots/transition_explode.gif).
However, what if I want to animate certain views of the entering activity differently? For example, if I have one view on the top half of the layout and one at the bottom of the layout, I may want to use a downwards slide transition on the top view and an upward slide animation on the bottom view.  Is this possible to set?

I can think of using [scene animations](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/master/screenshots/scenes_anim.gif) ([documented here](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations#3-animate-view-layout-elements)) and bringing in the elements from the sides of an empty view, but my layout is complicated and I am iterating it often, so keeping track of two different layouts for it is not really ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it! The idea is to create custom transition in xml and to set there targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="together">
    <slide
        android:slideEdge="top">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@id/toolbar"/>
        </targets>
    </slide>
    <slide
        android:slideEdge="bottom">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@id/text"/>
        </targets>
    </slide>
</transitionSet>
```

Comment: Can you send complete example?

Comment: @ApurvAjayKumarA2K You just need to inflate this transition using TransitionInflater to Transition object and then set it to activiry window (e.g. in your activity's onCreate method (Java): Transition t = TransitionInflater.from(this).        inflateTransition(R.transition.transitionset_resource_name); getWindow().setEnterTransition(t);). The same way you can use it with fragments.

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val t =   TransitionInflater.from(this)
                .inflateTransition(R.transition.animationgroup) as Transition
            window.setEnterTransition(t)
        }    not working . how to apply on activity

Answer (score 0):

To apply animation to desired view like button, textview, imageview, etc check this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Create four XML files for animation:
/res/anim/anim_alpha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <alpha
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.1"
       android:duration="500"
       android:repeatCount="1"
       android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

/res/anim/anim_rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <rotate
       android:fromDegrees="0"
       android:toDegrees="360"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="500"
       android:startOffset="0"
       android:repeatCount="1"
       android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

/res/anim/anim_scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <scale
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:toXScale="3.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="3.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="500"
       android:repeatCount="1"
       android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

/res/anim/anim_translate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0"
       android:toXDelta="100%p"
       android:duration="500"
       android:repeatCount="1"
       android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
</set>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hello" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/translate"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:text="Translate" />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/alpha"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:text="Alpha" />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/scale"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:text="Scale" />
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/rotate"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:text="Rotate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity:

```
package com.exercise.AndroidAnimButtons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidAnimButtonsActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       final Animation animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_translate);
       final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);
       final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_scale);
       final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);

       Button btnTranslate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translate);
       Button btnAlpha = (Button)findViewById(R.id.alpha);
       Button btnScale = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scale);
       Button btnRotate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rotate);

       btnTranslate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   arg0.startAnimation(animTranslate);
  }});

       btnAlpha.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   arg0.startAnimation(animAlpha);
  }});

       btnScale.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   arg0.startAnimation(animScale);
  }});

       btnRotate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   arg0.startAnimation(animRotate);
  }});
   }
}
```